# Why am I getting space stacking v-for list and a regular a tag?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm rendering a list of icon-links, using v-for and right after it adding a few other icon-list items.

Why am I getting space with the items attached at the end? 
Obviously, I checked my css and it has no rules for any margin, padding, etc.

As you can see, without v-for, every item in the list have this space around it.

```
<span style="padding-top:10px;display: block;">
  <a v-for="s in social.sites" :href="s.userPageUrl" target="_blank">
    <img :src="s.iconUrl" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" :width="social.wh" :height="social.wh">
  </a>
  <a :href="contacts.skype"><img src="imgurl" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" :width="social.wh" :height="social.wh"></a>
  <a :href="contacts.skype"><img src="imgurl" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" :width="social.wh" :height="social.wh"></a>
  <a :href="contacts.skype"><img src="imgurl" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" :width="social.wh" :height="social.wh"></a>
</span>
```

[image]

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    demoL: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png",
    social: {
      sites: [
       { 
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png",
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       },
       {
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png", 
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       },
       {
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png", 
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       }
    ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<span style="display: block;">
  <a v-for="s in social.sites" :href="s.userPageUrl">
    <img :src="s.iconUrl" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20">
  </a>
  
  
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a>
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a>
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a>
</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe the space is from your skype image itself. Just to check, replace the skype image with the other icons that didn't have any space on them and see if it still occurs.

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac no the skype icon is fine. I still get this space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic (block level) solution is to give the children:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

and apply `overflow: hidden;` to parent (extends its background to include all floating children).

The modern solution, applicable to your case, is to give the parent `display:flex` (if there's any case in which you want the children to wrap, also add `flex-wrap:wrap` to it).

---

**Why?**
By default, anchors have `display:inline`. Which means they are displayed as letters in text, as far as you're concerned. When you write `l e t t e r s` you don't expect browsers to remove the spaces between your letters.
Why do you expect it when the letters are... anchors?

As an alternative, you can simply remove any spaces or tabs between the end of an `<a>` tag and the beginning of the next.

The above is a bit of a simplification, but it's enough to understand the cause.

Here's why it's a simplification: any `display:inline` element can contain other elements and spaces, which will determine how the inline content will wrap, according to `text-wrap` property. Or, its elements can have a `display` value other than `inline` which will disrupt the inline behaviour of the parent as well. So a better association would be with words in text, not with letters.

For the intents and purposes of your question, either making the children `inline-block`s and floating them or giving the parent a `display` value of `flex` or `inline-flex` will work. Alternatively, you could effectively remove any space, tab or new line character in between your `>` and `<`.

A handy way of removing the spaces (while keeping your code in a readable position) is to place the ending character of your closing tag on the next line:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    demoL: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png",
    social: {
      sites: [
       { 
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png",
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       },
       {
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png", 
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       },
       {
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png", 
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       }
    ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<span style="display: block;">
  <a v-for="s in social.sites" :href="s.userPageUrl">
    <img :src="s.iconUrl" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20">
  </a
  ><a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a
  ><a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a
  ><a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a></span></div>
```

However, this technique is **not recommended** in production environments, especially when more than one developer is working on the same codebase, as it's too fragile and errors would be hard to spot.

Controlling their display behavior via CSS is the proper way to go.

Flexbox solution:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    demoL: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png",
    social: {
      sites: [
       { 
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png",
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       },
       {
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png", 
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       },
       {
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png", 
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       }
    ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<span style="display:flex;">
  <a v-for="s in social.sites" :href="s.userPageUrl">
    <img :src="s.iconUrl" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20">
  </a>
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a>
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a>
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a></span></div>
```

Inline blocks solution:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    demoL: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png",
    social: {
      sites: [
       { 
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png",
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       },
       {
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png", 
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       },
       {
         iconUrl: "https://i.imgur.com/Nk3PKVZ.png", 
         userPageUrl: "sdf"
       }
    ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app > span {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#app > span > a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<span style="display:block;">
  <a v-for="s in social.sites" :href="s.userPageUrl">
    <img :src="s.iconUrl" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20">
  </a>
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a>
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a>
  <a href=""><img :src="demoL" style="display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 4px;" nosend="1" width="20" height="20"></a></span></div>
```

Comment: The weird thing is that there is _no_ space between the `v-for`-generated anchors, though their display is still `inline`.

Comment: Why is it weird? Why are you expecting a `v-for` to output any spaces between its elements?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Then why do the last 3 items have this space? As you can see in the updated post there're no spaces and tabs but its still there.

Comment: It was throwing me because I was in the inspector and the elements display on separate lines.

Comment: All tabs and space characters between `display:inline` elements are reduced to a single space character by browsers. That's why you need `<br>` in html for actual EOL.

Comment: For some reasons the idea was to use inline styles. I didn't mention it in my post. My fault. Removing the spaces worked just fine.

Comment: Inline styles negate the principle of separating form from function, which is pretty much why CSS were invented. In short, inline styles do not scale, while stylesheets help change how a website looks without having to go through the markup. I'm glad my answer helped you solve your issue, but I also answered for future visitors with a similar problem, and inline styles are rarely a requirement.